# rpc.target.bits management?

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin, pushpool, stratum

I have a new question...

Is the max settings for `rpc.target.bits` 20? I want to match this with our stratum mining software, and how many shares we're getting.
Right now, pushpool is getting more shares (100 more over 2000 total). I tried setting difficulty to 21, but then i only got half of what stratum gave me...

So the real question here is... How to optimize? How to fix so it's as closely to Stratum's difficulty as possible?

Thanks.